# How to measure up/download speed from my apache web server?

Tags: apache-2.2

I wish to see who has accessed my server and what speed they have downloaded the website at.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

'Who' can be seen in  your access logs, the location of which is configurable but defaults (in debian) to /var/log/apache2/access.log

'What speed' can be garnered by using the [Custom Log module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html) and dividing %B (bytes sent) by %T (time to serve the request).

Comment: +1 on the speed calculation - I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

If by "who", you mean "what IP addresses", then yes, that information should be in your apache access_log. Also in that log, you'll find information as far as how much data was tranferred.